# XeTeX: Exclude characters from being rendered as italics in math mode (unicode-math)

Tags: math-mode, xetex, unicode, unicode-math, characters

So I'm relatively new to TeX in general and decided to go with XeTeX, mainly because I really like the approach to render the characters and symbols as actual Unicode-chars, so that you can expect appropiate behaviour when you're trying to copy a symbol. Copying a "∑" in LaTeX will often yield an "X", whereas unicode-math will render and yield an actual "∑", for instance.

Everything works fine, but the alphabetical characters are a big problem for me. I want to allow readers and myself to search for both latin and greek characters, such as "a" and "α", in the math mode.
This doesn't work out of the box, as "a" and "α" will be rendered to actual Unicode-italic "" and "".

I tried to work around this problem by adding

```
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{lmroman12-italic.otf}[range=it]
```

but that just leads to (1) the content of the math mode being squished together and (2) greek letters not being rendered, it fulfills the purpose otherwise.

To sum it up: I want alphabetical characters in the math mode to look italic, but them to **be** their normal ASCII-correspondent (just like in LaTeX) while still using XeTeX because of all the other advantages.

Is there a fully functioning workaround?
I browsed through the documentation for a while but haven't found a solution yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wonder if this is dependent on viewer. I can successfully search for 'a' and 'α' (without any hacks) in both Chromium and Zathura, but not in Acroread (under Linux).

Comment: If you change a mathematical  so that it is searched as a text a, it will also copy as text a. So you are actually losing the unicode meaning, and this is bad for e.g. accessibility. Instead of changing the pdf it would be better to make a feature request for the pdf viewer to allow `a` and `` to be alias. Beside this: If I wanted to search for an `a` in a formula I would greatly prefer if the search doesn't also find all the `a` in the text.

Comment: Welcome! It is really easy to confuse the symbol with the plain text, but  (math) and *a* are different glyphs. "Mathematical italic small a" =  = U+1D44E, while "Latin small letter a" = text a (normal, bold, italic, bolditalic) = U+0061. In Acrobat Reader DC (on Windows), searching must be by codepoint value, because looking for  finds only the maths symbol. Besides which, symbol  is different to symbol  ("mathematical sans-serif italic small a" = U+1D622), and so on for all the other 11 mathematical Latin alphabets. (Notice how the web page displays the symbol  as serif.)

Comment: Unrelated: math mode removes spaces to indicate multiplication; Latin Modern Roman has 24 uppercase Greek (text) letters, but no Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols at all (Latin or Greek). Latin Modern Math has upper and lowercase Greek (text) letters, plus 945 out of 996 Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols (plus "Basic Latin" text of course, 95 out of 128 = basically what is on the keyboard).

Comment: Just for fun and to test the browser (and to show the MAS range), here are all the MAS alphabets (and they would all be in a single font): . The italic and bold are part of the symbol definition. And this is text: aφ3 (the display will be according to the web page settings - e.g. sans-serif; and to make italic/bold, I apply formatting *aφ3* **aφ3**, but the codepoint value is the same as the plain characters).